# How do I improve replacement of text in my code? I'm using Regex currently to split strings

Tags: c#, regex, text, replace

I have a bit of code that works great on smaller files, but when the files are bigger the program locks up - or is just so slow it appears to be - I can walk away for 10 minutes and it's still sitting there. How do I improve the efficiency of this code for larger files? Also, something minor - when it's at the last split, the next item has nothing to split and I end up with a duplicate replace. How do I fix this? The efficiency issue is obviously my main problem here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < divs.Count; i++)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("</div>");
    string[] hands = regex.Split(divs[i].ToString());

    string output = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in hands)
    {

        output += item + "</div>";
        string text = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
        text = text.Replace("style = \"#\" >", textBox1.Text);
        ////style = "#" > 
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }


    //supposed to output the array to a message box
    MessageBox.Show(output);
}
```

Comment: For me, it is not clear what are you trying to do. How does `text` relate to `output` and `item`?

Comment: Mandatory link for "how to parse HTML with regex": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . Please use HtmlAgilityPack (or any other HTML parsing library) if indeed you are parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you need a regex, try [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

It also looks like you are parsing HTML with RegEx, consider using a HTML parser.

If the files are large avoid `ReadAllText` as this will load the entire file into memory consider [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - but an HTML parser would be better.

And do you really need to update the `richTextBox1.Text` property each time around the loop?

You are reading the entire file each time around the loop? Why?

Move everything that doesn't absolutely have to happen inside the loops outside (before or after).

Comment: Thank you. I will explore that area for my problem.

Comment: No I don't need it in the loop. I built around that and forgot to remove it. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious improvement would be to use `String.Split` in favor of RegEx. It is sufficient here and performs much better. So the first change I would make would be to change;

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("</div>");
  string[] hands = regex.Split(divs[i].ToString());
```

to

```
  string[] hands = divs[i].Split(new string[] { "</div>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

As pointed out in the other answer `File.ReadAllText` has some limitations that the `StreamReader` approach does not. However, you'll only run into them if your files are extremely large or the system the software is running on is lacking in RAM. In the main code base I currently work on `File.ReadAllText` and `File.ReadAllLines` are almost always the method used to read files.

Comment: between what everyone said, my code is now a bit more optimized and works on larger files now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See what effect each of these has on performance:

1. Move the 'File.ReadAllText out of that loop. It gets the same text every time.
2. Move the 'regex = new Regex' outside of the loop, and use the 'compiled' overload.
3. use a stringbuilder instead of string concatenation.
4. use the stopwatch classes to get timing for parts of the code to see where the time is spent.
5. Watch out for Cthulu.

Comment: thanks, i kept hearing strange noises outside and couldn't figure out what that was. as far as optimization, i will do what you say.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a for loop in the other and do Read a file in the loop. It's not a good idea for your situation. You can use stack to recognize when is appear close tag "".